# How do I get the latlng after the dragend event in leaflet?

Tags: event-handling, leaflet

I'm trying to update the lat/lng value of a marker after it is moved.  The example provided uses a popup window to display the lat/lng.

I have a "dragend" event listener for the marker, but when I alert the value of e.latlng it returns undefined.

javascript:

```
function markerDrag(e){
    alert("You dragged to: " + e.latlng);
}

function initialize() {
    // Initialize the map
    var map = L.map('map').setView([38.487, -75.641], 8);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>',
        maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);

    // Event Handlers
    map.on('click', function(e){
        var marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, {draggable:true});
        marker.bindPopup("<strong>"+e.latlng+"</strong>").addTo(map);

        marker.on('dragend', markerDrag);
    });
}


$(document).ready(initialize());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rhewitt/Msrpq/4/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

latlng value is not in e.latlng but in e.target._latlng . 
Use console.

Comment: How did you use the console to find that it was actually `e.target._latlng`?

Comment: put a debugger in fiddle

Comment: Give an example? I don't know how to console out a property I'm not aware of.

Comment: write 
    "debugger";  
where you want to break and open the console.(reload the page :) ) . Once the break point is hit, hover over the property or type in console. You can see all the contents.

this will help..
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: It's better to use `e.target.getLatLng()`; that way we're not exposing any private variables.

Answer (score 24):

Use `e.target.getLatLng()` to get the latlng of the updated position.

```
// Script for adding marker on map click
function onMapClick(e) {

    var marker = L.marker(e.latlng, {
             draggable:true,
             title:"Resource location",
             alt:"Resource Location",
             riseOnHover:true
            }).addTo(map)
              .bindPopup(e.latlng.toString()).openPopup();

    // #12 : Update marker popup content on changing it's position
    marker.on("dragend",function(e){

        var changedPos = e.target.getLatLng();
        this.bindPopup(changedPos.toString()).openPopup();

    });
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kedar2a/LnzN2/2/)

Comment: The key piece of this that answers the OP's question is `ev.target.getLatLng()`.

Comment: Is there anyway for folium, I can't find this answer for folium.

Comment: This is what I want, but on folium.

Answer (score 10):

While using `e.target._latlng` works (as proposed by [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18383612/2441511)), it's better practice to use

```
e.target.getLatLng();
```

That way we're not exposing any private variables, as is recommended by [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html):

> Private properties and methods start with an underscore (_). This doesn’t make them private, just recommends developers not to use them directly.

Comment: e.target.getLatLng is not a function

Comment: BTW, `const { lat, lng } = e.target.getCenter();` is working perfectly for me

Answer (score 10):

I think the API changed.

Nowadays is: `const { lat, lng } = e.target.getCenter();`

Comment: What object are you clicking on and what version of Leaflet?  I only see the `getCenter()` method available for `L.map`, `L.latLngBounds` and `L.polyline` for [Leaflet 1.0.3](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html).  On the other hand, `getLatLng()` is available for `L.marker`, `L.popup`, and `L.circleMarker`.

Comment: The API has not changed. In 1.3.0, for markers, this is still `e.target.getLatLng()`.

Comment: This helped!  On Leaflet version 1.0.3 here.  No `getLatLng` method.  I got as far to looking in the console and found various `L.Point` classes, but this was the data I wanted.  Even in the source version of Leaflet, I only saw the `target` object as `NewClass`, which didn't help  for looking through the docs online, and I also did not see much in the way of a "move" event that I was using.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is using react than you should use :

```
const map = useMap()
map.addEventListener("dragend" , ()=> {
const {lat , lng} = map.getCenter()
})
```