# event.latLng is undefined in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

For some reason I'm getting `undefined` in the console, but I'm not sure why.

```
var mp = document.getElementById('map'), ms = mp.style, center = L.latLng(47.62, -122.3321), h = innerHeight-130;
var tl = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'});
ms.height = h+'px';
var map = L.map('map', {center:center, zoom:10, layers:[tl]});
// remove when deployed
map.on('click', function(e){
  console.log(e.latLng);
});
```

Yet, if I change `console.log(e.latLng)` to `console.log(e)`, I'm seeing a result. According to their own [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#event-objects), it should work. Why doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

`e.latLng` should have been `e.latlng`. Hard to see case sensitive issue.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [How do I get the latlng after the dragend event in leaflet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382945/how-do-i-get-the-latlng-after-the-dragend-event-in-leaflet).

> latlng value is not in e.latlng but in e.target._latlng . Use console.