# How to add Search bar in leaflet maps and how to assign latitude and longitude of searched location to variables, so I can use them later

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps

How to assign latitude and longitude to latt and lngg ?

```
     <script>
     var lngg, latt;
     var map = L.map('map').setView([19.8684798, 75.3218784], 10);
            
             map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'));    
 
             map.addControl( new L.Control.Search({
                     url: 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q={s}',
                     jsonpParam: 'json_callback',
                     propertyName: 'display_name',
                     propertyLoc: ['lat','lon'],
                     marker: L.marker([0,0]),
                     autoCollapse: true,
                     autoType: false,
                     minLength: 2
                 })
             );
         L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                     attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
             }).addTo(map);


       </script>
```

I checked documentation but I'm unable to understand how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the 'search bar' as a variable and listen to the search events.

```
    var search = new L.Control.Search({
      url: 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q={s}',
                     jsonpParam: 'json_callback',
                     propertyName: 'display_name',
                     propertyLoc: ['lat','lon'],
                     marker: L.marker([0,0]),
                     autoCollapse: true,
                     autoType: false,
                     minLength: 2
  });

search.on('search:locationfound',
      function(e) {
          //You can get your required lat/lon this way 
          console.log(e.latlng)
          
           })

map.addControl( search );
```

Comment: That's Working ! Thank you so much.

Comment: I used  " map.on('click', onMapClick); "  function, onMapClick() update the marker when we drag marker , but it update only after user click on map so if user haven't click on map the after dragging marker the marker location won't update, so how to use, so how to use on load ( i tried  map.on('click', onMapClick) but it's not working )

Comment: @SaurabhDhakne that's 2 questions. Can you accept the answer as correct and your second question check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382945/how-do-i-get-the-latlng-after-the-dragend-event-in-leaflet).

Comment: Yes! the answer is absolutely Right. Thanx.